# Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms

Tags: ios, react-native, automation, appium, simulator

```
import wd from 'wd';

jest.setTimeout(60000);
const PORT = 4723;

const config = {
  platformName: 'iOS',
  deviceName: `iPhone X`,
  platformVersion: '12.2',
  app: '/path/to/my.app',
  useNewWDA: true,
  autoLaunch: false,
};
let screenshotIndex = 0
const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote('localhost', PORT);
directory = '../screenshots';`enter code here`

beforeAll(async () => {
  await driver.init(config);
  await driver.sleep(7000); // wait for app to load
});

afterEach(async () => {
  await driver.takeScreenshot().then(
    function (image, err) {
      require('fs').writeFile(`screenshot-${screenshotIndex++}.png`, image, 'base64');
    }
  );
});

test('appium renders', async () => {
  let contexts = await driver.contexts();
  console.log('contexts', contexts);
  await driver.context(contexts[1]);
  await driver.elementById('username').type('abc@example.com');
  await driver.elementById('password').type('#1234');
  await driver.elementById('Login').click();

});
```

//Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 60000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

After I run this I get the above error. Not sure where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try setting *setTimeout* to **node** *setTimeout* rather than default `jest.setTimeout`

```
// add below after import
global.setTimeout = require("timers").setTimeout
```